# Is there a link between Training, Test errors based on k fold CV and not doing CV?

Tags: cross-validation, training

I am using Matlab to train a feedforward NN using Cross validation (CV) approach. My understanding of CV approach is the following. (Please correct me where wrong)

1. Let `X` be the entire dataset with `Y` as the label set. Split `X` into 90/10 ratio to get: `[Xtrain,Xtest]` using holdout approach by calling the `cvpartition(Y,'Holdout',0.1,'Stratify',true)`
2. Apply CV on `Xtrain`: For every fold I calculated the accuracy. At the end of the CV loop I have an average accuracy score. Let `accCV` denote this variable. Inside the CV loop `xtrain` is further split into `[xtrain_cv,xtrain_val]`.
3. After CV loop, I reinitialze the weights and re-train a new model using `Xtrain`. Then I get a training accuracy which I denote by the variable `accTrain`.
4. Using the model obtained in Step3 I test for evaluating the model's purpose and consider this to be the generalization performance that is the performance when we have an unseen future data, `Xtest`. I call this accuracy as `accTest`.

**Question1:** Is it possible that `accCV` will be less than the accuracy over the train set `Xtrain` when not using the CV approach? That is I call the NN model over `Xtrain` only once and record the accuracy and denote it by variable `accTrain`, then is it possible that `accCV ~ accTrain`?. Or intuitively, `accCV` should be close to the accuracy when not using CV approach since the dataset is the same which is `Xtrain`. If this is the case, then why use CV when outside the CV we do not reuse the model that was created inside the CV? What does it tell us?

**Question2**: If `accCV < accTest` but the accuracy on the entire dataset `Xtrain` without using CV is close to that of `accTest` (`accTrain ~ accTest`) are we doing something wrong? What is the best case scenario? Is it `accCV ~ accTest`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected that `accCV < accTrain`: the former is the accuracy on the *test folds* (averaged over all the splits), so represents models' scores on unseen-to-them data.  Similarly, you would expect `accTrain > accTest`.

There are two main reasons to evaluate a model, whether by k-fold cross-validation or simple train/test split: for hyperparameter optimization / model selection, or to estimate future performance.  (N.B., k-fold should generally give better predictions than simple train/test split.)  If you make any decisions based on the scores, then they no longer represent unbiased estimates of future performance.  If, in your setup, you make no decisions based on step 2, then you should expect `accCV ~ accTest`, and there's no real reason to include that step.  If you *do* make decisions based on step 2, you may expect `accCV > accTest`, though the gap is probably substantially smaller than the gap in `accTrain > accTest`.  You may see discrepancies here, due to natural variation in the datasets, or perhaps data leakage.

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer, however few points are unclear. Could you please clarify?(1) I could not understand what you meant:"If you make any decisions based on the scores, then they no longer represent unbiased estimates of future performance." Did you mean to have a separate unseen data representing future data that should not be used in the CV loop and use this dataset for performance evaluation?(2)If `accCV~accTest` then is it a good or bad thing?(3) Is my creation of the test set (future unseen) which is never used in the CV loop correct? I called `accTest` for this test set.

Comment: (1,3) Your setup, with a k-fold CV on the train set and a separate test set, is most commonly used when you want to do model selection: you fit many models with CV on the train set, choose the model pipeline with best `accCV`, refit _that pipeline_ to the entire training set, and finally score on the test set getting `accTest`.  If you are not doing model selection, then you can get rid of either your step 2 or 4.  Read some of the Related questions.  (2) `accCV~accTest` is good; if not, then your test set is not iid with train set, or you have some data leakage, or...

Comment: Just to confirm, by `accTrain` you meant the training accuracy on 90% of  the split data set that was used inside the CV procedure and which is not the train data in the CV fold. Also, if we do training by CV then there is no need for a separate test set for generalization purpose since the test fold will serve that purpose. Is my understanding correct? Thank you very much for your help andclarifications.

Comment: Yes on both counts.